# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' - when I'm writing a function to insert an element into sorted linked list

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing a function to implement insertion into a sorted singly linked list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def isListEmpty(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return True
        return False

    def listLength(self):
        length = 0
        currentNode = self.head
        while currentNode is not None:
            length += 1
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        return length

    def insertAt(self, newNode, position):
        if position < 0 or position > self.listLength():
            print("Invalid Position")
            return
        elif position == 0:
            self.insertHead(newNode)
        else:
            currentPosition = 0
            currentNode = self.head
            while currentPosition is not position:
                currentPosition += 1
                previousNode = currentNode
                currentNode = currentNode.next
            newNode.next = currentNode
            previousNode.next = newNode

    def insertSort(self, newNode):
        if self.isListEmpty():
            self.insertEnd(newNode)
        else:
            currentPosition = 0
            currentNode = self.head
            while True:
                currentData = currentNode.data  # line with error
                if currentData <= newNode.data:
                    currentPosition += 1
                    currentNode = currentNode.next
            self.insertAt(newNode, currentPosition)

firstNode = Node(10)
link = LinkedList()
link.insertEnd(firstNode)
fifthNode = Node(25)
link.insertSort(fifthNode)
```

Currently getting the error:

```
     currentData = currentNode.data
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

I can't even guess what's the problem with the code.
I tried to print the node data with `print(currentNode.data)` but it shows no error, it comes error only during the condition check.

Comment: You don't need to guess, the stack trace points you to the exact line.

Comment: You never exit that loop. Eventually `currentNode.next` will become `None`, then you store that `None` in `currentNode`

Comment: you need to check if `currentPosition` is the desired value, and also check if the node is `None` (the end of the linked list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
currentData = currentNode.data  # line with error
if currentData <= newNode.data:
    currentPosition += 1
    currentNode = currentNode.next
self.insertAt(newNode, currentPosition)
```

Here you never exited the while loop.
So, final currentNode will contain None. Check if you reached to the end of the LinkedList and exit.

I would like to add one more thing.

```
while currentPosition is not position:
            currentPosition += 1
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        newNode.next = currentNode
        previousNode.next = newNode
```

This loop in InsertAt function you need to know whether the position mentioned is correct or not. Let's say the total number of positions were 25 and the entered position was 30. Now your loop will fail as it would never reach to 30. So you need to add one exit loop in while condition itself saying:

```
while ((currentPosition is not position) and (currentNode is not None))
```

Now the code will never fail.